# Authenticate in LDAP using Digest?

Tags: .net, asp.net, authentication, ldap, digest

My web application is using Digest authentication. There is no user password on server side. Now I need to authenticate a user in LDAP.

Is it possible? Any example in .Net/C#?

I can modify my Digest implementation algorithm, but I can not change it to Basic or any other authentication due to requirements.

**Edit:** As far as I see there is System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapConnection.AuthType property that can be set to AuthType.Digest. How do I use this setting?

Comment: Read about SASL. There are some SASL mechanisms that do not require transmission of passwords.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no.

You are *required* to supply a plain-text password to the LDAP auth routine programmatically, which you cannot get from Digest - that's kind of the point of Digest.

The only work around I can think of is to connect to LDAP with a high-level account, and check whether the user could do what they are trying to do with that.

If you are trying to validate the user's login with LDAP, your a bit stuffed really. This is why most web services that authenticate against AD are either Basic auth over HTTPS, or use NTLM auth...

Comment: a) LdapConnection.AuthType can be set to AuthType.Digest. b) IIS can use Digest authentication somehow. c) NTLM itself is a sort of Digest as far as I know. So I think the Digest is supported.

Comment: Granted the underlying LDAP protocol can use Digest, but you still have to supply a plain-text password to the high level functions you are calling - you can't do the Digest hash calculation yourself. Even if you could, your HTTP Auth Realm would have to match the LDAP auth realm, and your nonces would have to match as well - it would be very hard to translate between two independent Digest transactions.

Comment: Digest works perfectly with Active Directory and no passwords are exchanged. Only challenges. Keep in mind that NTLM is rather insecure and Digest is the superior scheme.

Answer (score 0):

It could be possible if your building something new.

You could add the HA1 as an attribute in LDAP when you create the user. HA1 = MD5(username : realm : password) for Http digest.

Then when the user access the web server and provide a Authorization header. You could rebuild the authorization using the HA1 from LDAP and compare the result... But you would need to access the user HA1 value using the system admin credential which is not the best way.